# "The file <file> could not be found in the repository" error when uploading a diff to reviewboard

Tags: svn, diff, patch, review-board

I'm Trying to upload a diff to review board and get the following error

```
The file '<file_path>' (r<revision>) could not be found in the repository
```

I'm using svn as the version control tool. The file mentioned was moved (renamed) which causes in svn to deletion and then addition of the file from svn. I want this file to be included in the review but can't.

Is there any workaround other then removing the file from the diff?

Answer (score 1):

I was just faced with the same problem, it looks like reviewboard uses the patch command and that doesn't support the format which svn diff generates.

Additionally if you change svn properties, then you'll see the following exception when clicking on "View Diff" in reviewboard:

```
Exception: The patch to '<file_path>' didn't apply cleanly. The temporary files have been left in '/tmp/reviewboard.CIjCx6' for debugging purposes.
`patch` returned: patch: **** Only garbage was found in the patch input.
```

---

I resolved both issues by passing `--patch-compatible` parameter to `svn diff`. When creating the diff like this reviewboard accepts it properly:

```
svn diff --patch-compatible
```

Excerpt from `svn help diff`:

```
--ignore-properties      : ignore properties during the operation
--show-copies-as-adds    : don't diff copied or moved files with their source
--patch-compatible       : generate diff suitable for generic third-party
                           patch tools; currently the same as
                           --show-copies-as-adds --ignore-properties
```